# Xpath query count

Tags: xpath, rest-assured, hamcrest

I'm looking at an XPath query in the project's code base:

`count(//*[local-name() = 'Offer'])`

I need to modify the code so that it checks for a count of 7. I don't know what that would look like.  Is it this?

`[count(//*[local-name() = 'Offer']) = 7]`

PS: I'm using Java and RestAssured to run a test. Looks like I have the option of using a Hamcrest matcher or an XmlAssert matcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is

```
count(//*[local-name() = 'Offer']) = 7
```

without the `[` and `]` brackets. This expression will check if the count of all descendants with the local name `Offer` is 7.
Of course, if you are using this as a predicate in a node check, the brackets are necessary.